# Javascript function document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, getelementbyid

I tried to create a function that changes the style of a table by using the parameter (table name) passed into the function. I am not sure what is wrong with my code as shown below, am I using the parameter correctly below. The parameter is the actual name of the table. It doesn't seem to work. I have tried putting it in quotes, using `$` but it does not seem to work. Am I using it incorrectly?

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
    function sizeTbl(table) 
    {                                           
        var tbl = document.getElementById(table);

        if(tbl.style.display == 'table-row')
        {
            tbl.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            tbl.style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am calling this function using the following:

```
<a href='javascript:sizeTbl("tbl0")'>View</a>
```

or

```
<a href='javascript:sizeTbl("tbl1")'>View</a>
```

etc.

I am trying to show and hide additional rows in a table using this function. The table is similar to the one below:

```
<table>
    <tr><a href='javascript:sizeTbl(tb10)'>Click Here to show the hidden row</a></tr> 
    <tr id="tbl0" style='display:none'><td>Initially Hidden Row</td></tr>;
</table>
```

Comment: table name or... id ?

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: please format the question using instructions from [following page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). 
For this particular question, pleaes provide the accompanied HTML markup

Comment: You need to put quotes around your table names; `sizeTbl('tbl0')`. Also you should be using `onclick` instead of `href` or better, add an event handler.

Comment: And this will only work if your table is `<table id="tbl0" ...` (as opposed to `<table name="tbl0" ...`)

Comment: yes dave, it should only work on the id passed into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use getElementbyName

```
 function sizeTbl(table) 
    {                                           
        var tbl= document.getElementsByName(table)[0];

        if(tbl.style.display == 'table-row')
        {
            tbl.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            tbl.style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how do I use the parameter in document.getElementsByName, in the function?

Comment: @DesiBoyz I updated to show you how.

Comment: what does the [0] do?

Comment: getelementbyname returns a nodelist of all elements with that name. So you use 0 to get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to the function should have a parameter wrapped in quotes:

```
<a href='javascript:sizeTbl("tbl0")'>View</a>
                            ^    ^
```

Comment: `'table-row'` is a valid property for `display`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Really? What does it mean?

Comment: It's what's used when rows are displayed in a table. http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table

Comment: It means display it as a table row, like `<tr>`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display